Why does the window get greyed out inside a tab when using this imgui code?
Window on first render or after switching tabs
Windows get greyed out  after clicking in the background black region of the tab
I am new to using imgui.
I am trying to display multiple windows in a tab selected by the user. The code I have written works almost as except for an inconvenient bug. Every time the user clicks in the tab background, the windows get greyed out and the windows cannot be brought back into focus.
The way to get them back is to switch tabs and come back to this tab.
This is how my code looks like (more or less)
if(ImGui::BeginTabItem(plot_window[i].name))  
{
    ImGui::SetNextWindowSize(ImVec2(200, 200), ImGuiCond_FirstUseEver);  
    ImGui::Begin("My first", &p_open);  
    ImGui::End();  
    ImGui::SetNextWindowSize(ImVec2(200, 200), ImGuiCond_FirstUseEver);  
    ImGui::Begin("My second", &p_open);  
    ImGui::End();  
    //ImGui::SetWindowFocus("My second");  
    ImGui::EndTabItem();  
} 

I tried to SetWindowFocus but the window this always forces focus on the second window. I need the windows to be displayed and available to the user at all times as long the tab is selected
